# QGIS OpenLayers Plugin shows black for OSM?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, openlayers, qgis-plugins

the QGIS OpenLayers Plugin version 1.4.3 shows all OSM WMS Layers broken with black- or redscreen "tiles". A colleaque had version 1.3.6 installed and it worked fine. I was already on 1.4.3 with broken layers. With the new version (1.4.2?) OSM layers was split up in two groups (OpenStreetMap, OSM/Thunderforest). After updating to 1.4.3 my colleaques OSM layers were also broken. We both use QGIS 2.18.0 on Windows7-64bit machines.

I searched Google, the Github-Repository and StackExchange but I can't find a bug report on this issue.

Comment: Works fine for me (QGIS 2.18.3 for Win7 64-bit, OL Plugin version 1.4.3). Did you make sure the **Project CRS** is in EPSG:3857?

Comment: Maybe this is useful for you: I also used the OpenLayers Plugin until I first tried QuickMapServices Plugin. That one is so much better. More services and way faster :-) You could try that one.

Comment: Thanks a lot! QuickMapServices looks great. That's a nice workaround!

Answer (score 1):

I Have QGIS 2.14.13 and OpenLayers Plugin 1.4.3 installed and here the Plugin works just fine.

However their is another Plugin for WMS Layers called *QuickMapServices*. This plugin also works fine when Printing the map, which OpenLayers Plugin does not.

[image]